# Can a TensorFlow Graph be loaded per FILE not directory with the C API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

It is for our project mandotary, that the **network is loaded by file** not per directory.

At the moment I load per directory the saved_model.pb this way and it is working:

```
auto tfSessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
runOpts = nullptr:
TF_Session * pSession = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel(tfSessionOpts,
                                                     runOpts,
                                                     m_strModelDir.c_str(),
                                                     m_vecTags.data(),
                                                     static_cast<int>(m_vecTags.size()),
                                                     m_graph,
                                                     nullptr,
                                                     status);
```

Now I have to switch to a load per file methode, while using the c_api. I have a frozen_graph.pb which I want to load in C and get some information from it for setup (tensors etc) and run the session. What I do is:

Loading the frozen_graph.pb into the buffer:

```
std::ifstream f(m_strModelFile, std::ios::binary);
if (f.seekg(0, std::ios::end).fail()) { throw; }
auto fsize = f.tellg();
if (f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg).fail()) { throw; }
if (fsize <= 0) { throw; }
auto data = static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(fsize));
if (f.read(data, fsize).fail()) { throw; }
TF_Buffer* pBuffer = TF_NewBuffer();
pBuffer->data = data;
pBuffer->length = fsize;
pBuffer->data_deallocator = DeallocateBuffer;
```

load the graph with the buffer (status is okay):

```
TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* pGraphDefOptions = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
TF_GraphImportGraphDef(m_graph, pBuffer, pGraphDefOptions, status);
```

load the session (status is okay):

```
auto tfSessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
TF_Session* session = TF_NewSession(m_graph, sessionOptions, status);
```

Well the buffer has the correct size, the graph and session is not nullptr and status says “ok”.
But when I want to use the graph, then there is no information I can use.
Like for example I can not get specific Operation:

```
auto input_op = TF_Output{ TF_GraphOperationByName(m_graph, "StatefulPartitionedCall"), 1 };
if (input_op.oper == nullptr)
{
 throw; // this happens
}
```

But I have access to this information, when I construct the graph with the TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel function.

Am I doing sth. wrong or can a graph with usefull information not be loaded per filename?

If it is not possible with the c_api, is it possible with the c++ API?

Comment: If you ask about a C++ solution, don't use tag C.

Comment: I'm asking about a solution with the C API. If its not possible with the C API, then I would be happy about a C++ API solution.

Comment: There isn't a "C++ API"; you use the C API inside C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you that you haven't loaded the graph ops?

```
std::unique_ptr<TF_ImportGraphDefOptions,
                decltype(&TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions)> graph_opts = {
TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions(), TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions};
TF_GraphImportGraphDef(m_graph.get(), def, graph_opts.get(),
                       status.get());
```